# Style JSX is not working properly with @media-query in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx, next.js

I am using `<style jsx>` in `Next JS` to style my components. When that code is compiled `@media query` isn't executed successfully.

Here is my `<style jsx>` part of the code

```css
.post__card .summary {
   width: 351px;
}

@media screen and(max-width: 1142px) {
   .post__card .summary {
       width: 80%;
   }
}
```

When code is compiled I have `jsx-2993501484 post__card` and `jsx-2993501484 summary` and JS is looking for

```css
@media screen and(max-width:1142px) {
    .post__card.jsx-2993501484 .summary.jsx-2993501484 {
        width: 80%;
    }
}
```

*(see image below)*

But for some reason style from `@media-query` is not applied to the element. That part of `CSS` is not even available in Inspect element in the browser

[image: Image one]
[image: Image two]

**System information**

OS: **Manjaro Linux**

Browser: **Chrome**

Version of Next.js: **^9.1.8-canary.13**

I also asked this question [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/10505)

Comment: Can you share the whole component code with us?

Comment: My bad for not doing it in the post. Unfortunately I can do in few hours because I am not on the job right now. But as soon as I get there I will share whole component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the current code

```css
@media screen and(max-width: 1142px) {
   .post__card .summary {
       width: 80%;
   }
}
```

This is fixed code

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1142px) {
   .post__card .summary {
       width: 80%;
   }
}
```

The problem was there there was no space between `and` and `(` in media query.

Comment: Try and use a CSS linter next time ;)